# Is there some way to pass the Locale for the EJB and generate a compilation error if not set?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

So, [it's better to pass the Locale to EJB via parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554150/is-it-a-bad-design-for-a-ejb-to-depend-on-facescontext), instead of get it myself from FacesContext;

Now, if I do use this parameter in every method, whats a good approach to set it only once?

I don't like the idea of a `setLocale()` method; I would like to force it to be set, with some compilation error (instead of seeing the error only later at runtime).

For [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328674/how-to-invoke-an-ejb-3-1-non-zero-arguments-constructor-from-a-servlet), looks like I can't use construtor parameter. The idea of setting the attribute in the request is nice, but the only way I know to get the request object is via `FacesContext`, what, again, [we don't want the FacesContext dependency inside the EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554150/is-it-a-bad-design-for-a-ejb-to-depend-on-facescontext).

Is there some way to force the developer to pass the Locale for the EJB? I mean, if not set, generate a compilation error?

Comment: What's the business of having `Locale` in backend? This is certainly worring given that it appears to be a frontend-managed one. Perhaps the task you had in mind with the `Locale` actually belongs in the frontend?

Comment: @BalusC I'll e-mail the client if the task succeed. And I have the e-mail texts in a `.properties` file. And to load that properties file I need the Locale. I was, just now, thinking about load the ResourceBundle and pass it to the EJB, instead of the Locale... But the question about how to force it to be passed continues (passing a single time, not in every single method).

Comment: So, there's a logged-in user and it's actually the user's preferred locale? When using container managed security, the logged-in user is just directly available in EJBs too.

Comment: @BalusC but I need the `.properties` data, not the logged-in user's.

Comment: I was talking about the locale. Is it actually the user's preferred locale or not?

Comment: @BalusC yes! Right. This answer the specific question, although I still would like to know how to set something to the EJB, with a compilation error if that was not set.

Comment: Service layer can't expect that from its client. Way too fishy. If you want statefulness, use a stateful EJB injected in an application scoped managed bean, or use a singleton EJB.